# How to show diffs of merge commits in magit?

Tags: magit

When viewing a merge commit it only shows the number of lines changed but no diff.

I know that it is possible with `git show --first-parent`. Is there a way to add an argument to `magit-show-commit`?

I'm aware that I can just diff from the commit view but I thought there may be a way to do it directly when viewing the commit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the diff dwim command instead (<kbd>d d</kbd>); it does what you want it to do in this case too.

Comment: DWIM can only use heuristics to infer what I actually mean and sometimes gets it wrong. How can I explicitly tell it what I want and how can I make it do so by default?

Comment: You can make it do its thing and then observe the result.

Comment: Problem is that the result isn't always what I mean.